# Retrieve geolocation periodically

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm developing an app that should send the user geolocation periodically ( interval of 3 minutes ). I was reading the android documentation and was wondering if i need to create an LocationListener on every activity/fragment that i have.

I was thinking about something like an Observer that runs like a 'silence thread' together with the app and send the data to my service. Is there something like it or i have to implement the LocationListener in every place?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Why not just send when the location changes?

Comment: You could set up a WakefulIntentService https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful having it query the latest location object and send it every 3 minutes

Comment: @stark good idea..i've implemented it on onLocationChanged and looks better but i'm trying to avoid to use third party libraries.. if i do this way, it's only few lines on my 'BaseActivity'

Answer (score 0):

I have some implementation that has the same requeriment, also remember that the device might lose connection when it's been located, so you might think in implementing saving the positions in sqlite. it looks like this:

WakefulAlarmListener.java

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.WakefulIntentService;
import com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.WakefulIntentService.AlarmListener;

/*
 * 
 * 
 * @see <a> href="https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful">https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful</a>
 * @see {@link AutoSendingWakefulIntentService}
 * 
 */
public class WakefulAlarmListener implements AlarmListener {


    @Override
    public void scheduleAlarms(AlarmManager alarmManager,PendingIntent pendingIntent, Context context) 
    {
        IOController ioController = new IOController(context);
        int autoSendingFrequency = Integer.parseInt(context.getString(R.string.default_autosending_frequency));
        // Este método permite que se puedan realizar operaciones de
        // red en el hilo de la interfaz gráfica (El alarmlistener se ejecuta en este hilo).
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) 
        {
            Log.d("WakefulAlarmListener => scheduleAlarms()", "Build version: "
                    + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + " >= "
                    + Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD
                    + " => setting thread policy...");
            setThreadPolicy();
        }       

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar
                .getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), autoSendingFrequency * 1000, pendingIntent);
    }


    @Override
    public void sendWakefulWork(Context context) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) 
        {
            context.startService(new Intent(context,LocationListenerDummyService.class));
        }                   
        IOController ioController = new IOController(context);
        int autoSendingFrequency = ioController.loadAutoSendingFrequency();
        int lastAutoSendingFrequency = ioController.loadLastAutoSendingFrequency();     
        if (autoSendingFrequency != -1)         
        {
            Log.d("sendWakefulWork()", "autoSendingFrequency=" + autoSendingFrequency);
            Log.d("sendWakefulWork()","lastAutoSendingFrequency=" + lastAutoSendingFrequency);
            if (autoSendingFrequency != lastAutoSendingFrequency) 
            {               
                WakefulIntentService.cancelAlarms(context);
                WakefulIntentService.scheduleAlarms(this, context);
            }
            else 
            {
                Log.d("sendWakefulWork()","autoSendingFrequency == lastAutoSendingFrequency");              
                WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context,AutoSendingWakefulIntentService.class);
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            WakefulIntentService.cancelAlarms(context);
            WakefulIntentService.scheduleAlarms(this, context);
            Log.d("sendWakefulWork()","autoSendingFrequency == -1");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Si detecta que la alarma no se lanzó en el número de milisegundos
     * devuelto, entonces asume que el usuario cerró la aplicación de forma
     * forzada y vuelve a programar la alarma.
     * 
     * Consultar la documentación de la biblioteca para más información.
     * 
     * @return Tiempo en milisegundos. En este caso es de 0 milisegundos.
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public long getMaxAge() {
        return 0;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    private void setThreadPolicy() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

}
```

AutosendeindWakefulIntenService.java

```
public class AutoSendingWakefulIntentService extends WakefulIntentService {


MDRCController myMDRC;

public AutoSendingWakefulIntentService() {
    super("AutoSendingWakefulIntentService");
}


@Override
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {               

    int timeout = Integer.parseInt((getString(R.string.autosending_timeout)));
    int sampleSize = Integer.parseInt((getString(R.string.autosending_samplesize)));
    boolean useNetworkLocation = Boolean.parseBoolean((getString(R.string.use_network_location_provider)));             
    int autoSendingTries = Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.autosending_connection_tries));
    final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    IOController myIO =new IOController(getApplicationContext());
    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation(getApplicationContext(),timeout, sampleSize, useNetworkLocation);

    Location location = null;                                                   
    location = myLocation.getLocation();

    sendLocationToServer(location, autoSendingTries);               
    sendPendingGeoEventToServerAndUpdateCollection();                       
    verifyBatteryLevel();
}

private void sendLocationToServer(Location location, int autoSendingTries) {

    IOController myIo= new IOController(getApplicationContext());
    ServerResponseParser serverResponseParser = new ServerResponseParser(getApplicationContext());      
    SQLDataSource mySqlDataSource = new SQLDataSource(getApplicationContext());     
    String type;
    int actioncode=0;

    Log.d("AutoSendingWakefulIntentService => sendLocationToServer()","Auto Sending Tries: " + autoSendingTries);
        if (location != null) 
        {               
            if (autoSendingTries > 0)                   
            {   
                myIo.saveLastLocationData(location);                    
                Log.d("AutoSendingWakefulIntentService => sendLocationToServer()",
                                   "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude()
                                + "; Longitude: " + location.getLongitude()
                                + "; Accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy());                            
                 if(location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) 
                 {
                   Log.d("AutoSending","GPS");
                   actioncode = Integer.parseInt(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.actioncode_automatic_gps), 16);                                             
                   GeoEvent myGeoEvent = new GeoEvent(location, actioncode, new  DeviceInformation(getApplicationContext()).getBatteryLevel());         
                        //FIXME  sendGeoEventToServer() ;                                      
                 }
                 else
                {
                    if(location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))

                   {
                       try {
                             type =location.getExtras().getString("networkLocationType");
                            }catch(NullPointerException ex){                         
                             type ="network";
                            }
                       if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("wifi") && !myIo.loadWifiForLocation())
                           {
                            Log.d("AutoSending","wifi");
                             actioncode = Integer.parseInt(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.actioncode_automatic_passive),16);    
                           }
                       else
                           {
                            Log.d("AutoSending","network");
                            actioncode = Integer.parseInt(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.actioncode_automatic_network),16);
                           }

                       GeoEvent myGeoEvent = new GeoEvent(location, actioncode, new  DeviceInformation(getApplicationContext()).getBatteryLevel());
                        mySqlDataSource.InsertGeoEvent(myGeoEvent);
                       //FIXME  sendGeoEventToServer()  ;                                      
                   } 
                 else if(location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER))
                   {
                       actioncode = Integer.parseInt(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.actioncode_automatic_passive),16);
                       //FIXME  sendGeoEventToServer()  ;                                      
                   }

                }                                                   

            } 
            else
            {
                Log.e("ASWIS=>sLTS()","Auto sending tries==0, Automatic location sending failed! Adding location to list...");                  
                GeoEvent myGeoEvent = new GeoEvent(location, actioncode, new  DeviceInformation(getApplicationContext()).getBatteryLevel());
                mySqlDataSource.InsertGeoEvent(myGeoEvent);

            }
        } 
        else 
        {

        }                   
}
```

}

and the alarm in the manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.AlarmReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful"
                android:resource="@xml/wakeful" />
        </receiver>
```

Comment: It's a good solution but i'm trying to avoid third party libraries and i don't know if i really need an AlarmManager. I've created a 'master' activity that is extended so i put the code of the location inside this class. It's not look good but it's working :)